# PHP - Deleting content of div doesn't work in specific file

Tags: php

I wrote a function which opens a HTML file, deletes the content of divs with a certain class and saves the file. I created 3 testfiles in three different locations. My function works great on site.html and site3.html, but not on site2.html

The folder structure is as the following:

/testing/script.php // contains my function

- /testing/site.html
- /testing/folder1/site2.html // script doesn't work in this file
- folder2/site3.html

The HTML of the files is identical

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div class="string">Content of site2.html</div>
<div id="well">not here</div>
<div id="empty"></div>
<div>foo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my script.php

```
<?php 

    $urls = array(
            "site.html",
            "/folder1/site2.html",
            "../folder2/site3.html"
        ); // get the urls of the files

    function DeleteContent () {

        global $urls;

        echo "DeleteContent is running";

        if (is_array($urls) || is_object($urls)) {
            foreach($urls as $url) {

                $dom = new DOMDocument;
                $dom->loadHTMLFile($url);
                $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
                $pDivs = $xpath->query(".//div[@class='string']");

                foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
                    $div->removeChild($div->firstChild);
                }

                $dom->saveHTMLFile($url);

            }
        }
    }

    DeleteContent();


?>
```

I get this error

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::removeChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given, called in /testing/script.php on line 57 and defined in /testing/script.php on line 29

// line 29 in original file (adjusted it for the question)

```
foreach ( $pDivs as $div ) {
    $div->removeChild($div->firstChild); // line 29
}
```

Comment: `/folder1/site2.html` thats relative to root

Comment: What happens when you make it a relative path (remove the first slash "folder1/site2.html",)?

Comment: @AaronW. Tried that too, there is no difference

Comment: I can't imagine the issue is with your code if all 3 of those files are _exactly_ the same.  Permissions? Try to var_dump the contents of each file and diff them?

Comment: Would it make more sense to just delete the whole div or are you needing to keep that container? `$div->parentNode->removeChild($div);` Otherwise, You need a loop because there's going to be lots of child node types, eg attributes (your @class is a child node), text nodes, other element nodes. etc and "firstChild" may not be what you expect.

Comment: @AaronW. Yes, the files are exactly the same. No, It can't be a permission problem. Sorry, I'm new to PHP. How should I var_dump the content of each file? Like that? var_dump($dom); I have put this in my foreach($urls as $url) {

Comment: @Scuzzy The reason I don't delete the whole div is because I also have AddContent function which I didn't mention here. It searches the divs with the specific class and adds content to it.

Comment: I just took your script and made a cut down version locally without the file loading, and... it worked without any problems using your sample HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can suggest is testing for firstChild before removing it, because your code otherwise seems fine.

```
foreach ( $pDivs as $div )
{
    if( $div->firstChild )
    {
      $div->removeChild( $div->firstChild );
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked! But I don't get really why. Isn't this code just testing if the div has a firstChild (firstChild = content in this case)? Sorry, I just started with PHP

Comment: I really don't know myself what exactly is going on, what you could do is dump the div with `var_dump($dom->saveHTML($div));` and `var_dump($dom->saveHTML($div->firstChild));` from within your loop to get an idea of what the code is working on

Comment: Gonna check that tomorrow. Btw, do you think that my code is safe to use? I want to use my script on pretty important files which are way larger than my testfiles. And secondly, do you know an easy solution to avoid that DOMXPath adds some tags and doctype?

Comment: Your approach seems sound, There is very little the user can interact with from a file system point of view. Not sure about the extra doctype stuff that is added to make a valid document, I'm sure there's some dom settings somewhere for that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that

```
<div id="empty"></div>
```

causes your "null-Exception". There is nothing to remove within.

Comment: You are right! How can I solve this problem? Because sometimes there might be an empty div within a file...

Comment: The xpath wouldn't have selected that div because its class attribute doesn't match the word `string`